# C# lost local variable window from debug (f11 step by step)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#

I was running my code (visual studio 2010) and I accidentally closed the window that shows the state of variables step by step. I think it was called locals but I can't find it on any of the menu option. Would appreciate any help on this, I didn't realize how handy it was until now  - The following link is what my local window looks like when selecting debug/start debugging/selecting breakpoints, which I'm don't find helpful.

This is what my window used to look like:

[image]

It's probably a mode/option within debugging I need to select but I can't figure out how to get it back to the nice and simple variable state display..

Comment: Is the picture that I posted accurate with your version of VS?

Comment: Your second link is broken for me

Comment: In future, it would be better if you could link directly to the image rather than the Google image result. I've trimmed the Google cruft from the link and inserted the image properly (please don't edit that link in again!), though @soandos's screenshot showed more or less the same thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be different in your version, but it should be in the same place:

[image]

Comment: Yes! Derp, I just tried debugging from the start of my program and the local window is back to normal (I hope). Maybe it was the method I was starting from... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you mean the debugger?  I believe you select `debug`, then `start debugging`, then walk through breakpoints that you have set.

Comment: I just selected those options, it shows all this other...stuff that my normal local window didn't have. Example: I press f11 and it will debug 1 line of code, I press it again and it debugs the next line etc showing only the state of variables that has been debugged in that section so far..if that makes sense..

Comment: Ya, thats how it usually works as far as I remember. I haven't coded in years tho